# Trying to bounce a box with a plane using bullet physics

Tags: c++, directx, directx11, bullet-physics

I'm trying to simulate a box that bounces with a plane and I'm beginner with bullet physics. I created a plane (box) and and a box that is falling. The problem is the ball is stalled while colliding with the plane and doesn't rotate (no bouncing effect), even if the box is rotated so that it can sharply bounce with the plane. Here is my configuration.

```
// in update
if (m_pBoxMotionState) 
    {
        btTransform transform;
        // get the world transform from our motion state
        m_pBoxMotionState->getWorldTransform(transform);

        btQuaternion quat;
        quat.setEuler(0, 290, 0); //or quat.setEulerZYX depending on the ordering you want
        transform.setRotation(quat);

        XMMATRIX world = btTransform_to_XMMATRIX(transform);
        m_Cube->Draw(world, m_Graphics.getViewMatrix(), m_Graphics.getProjectionMatrix());
    }

// Init
    m_Grid.CreateGrid(360.0f, 360.0f, 50, 50); // width*depth, 360*360
    m_Grid.SetPosition(1, -90, 1);
    m_Cube = GeometricPrimitive::CreateCube(m_Graphics.getContext(), 5.0f, false);

      m_pCollisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
            // create the dispatcher
            m_pDispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(m_pCollisionConfiguration);
            // create the broadphase
            m_pBroadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
            // create the constraint solver
            m_pSolver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
            // create the world
            m_pWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(m_pDispatcher, m_pBroadphase, m_pSolver, m_pCollisionConfiguration);
            m_pWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));

            btBoxShape* pBoxShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
            // give our box an initial position of (0,0,0)
            btTransform transform;
            transform.setIdentity();
            transform.setOrigin(btVector3(0.0f, 50, 0.0f));
            pBoxShape->calculateLocalInertia(4, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
            // create a motion state
            m_pBoxMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(transform);
            // create the rigid body construction info object, giving it a 
            // mass of 1, the motion state, and the shape
            btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo(4.0f, m_pBoxMotionState, pBoxShape);
            btRigidBody* pRigidBody = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);
            pGroundShape->calculateLocalInertia(0, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
            btBoxShape* pGroundShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(360, 1,360));
            btTransform groundShapeTransform;
            groundShapeTransform.setIdentity();
            groundShapeTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(1.0f, -90.0f, 1.0f));

            // create a motion state
            m_pGroundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(groundShapeTransform);
            btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbGroundInfo(0, m_pGroundMotionState, pGroundShape);
            rbGroundInfo.m_friction = 1.0f;
            rbGroundInfo.m_restitution = 1.0f;
            btRigidBody* pRigidBodyGround = new btRigidBody(rbGroundInfo);

            // inform our world that we just created a new rigid body for 
            // it to manage
            m_pWorld->addRigidBody(pRigidBodyGround);
            m_pWorld->addRigidBody(pRigidBody);
```

Comment: Are you sure your rendering code is reading back the rotation component of the motion state and not just the translation?

Comment: @Steven I'm giving the cube the rotation and translation part here:  
        m_Cube->Draw(world, m_Graphics.getViewMatrix(), m_Graphics.getProjectionMatrix());
is that not correct?

Comment: @Steven the cube is rotated actually with the quat.setEuler(0, 290, 0);

Comment: I wanted to ensure that you were not accidentally setting the rotation of the matrix every frame